Detached object with list of items in Entity Framework Core not deleting deleted items
What is the best way to update an object and its relations in Entity Framework Core when one of the items in the relation is deleted?
If I have the following classes:
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

And I have a blog with Id = 1 that has 10 posts in the database.
If I have a detached Blog object
Blog blog

with all 10 posts in memory, and I want to edit the name of the blog, delete one of the posts and and a new post, why is it not possible to simply do the operations on the blog object and call
dbContext.Blogs.Update(blog)

This operation will only update the blog name, add the new post, but it will not delete the post I want to delete. I would simply assume that it Entity Framework Core can detect the differences and perform the necessary SQL operations.
What is the best way to do what I want?

If you want to detect changes why do you have a detached object?

I do not want to detect changes. I want to apply the changes to the database so that the corresponding object is updated. But i want the Posts which are not in the list to be deleted in the database

Why do you have a detached object when you actually want an attached object, where you can make the changes on and save them?

This question is similar to: How to update a detached object with a collection inside on EF Core?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is similar but my question has issues with deleted object. I have modified the title and some of the content of my post to indicate this.

@Progman I have a detached object because that is what is sent to me by the UI when the user wants to update the object. So UI sends the object with the modified properties and deleted Posts and i want to apply that update to the corresponding object in the database.

You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429663/how-to-save-combined-newmodified-detached-entities-in-entity-framework. Basically, you have to iterate over the collection items and check, if they still exists in the database or not.

Now the question becomes, why is "the UI" detaching the object instead of using a tracked entity?

Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357569/5045688
